# File Organizer and Indexer for an External SSD Drive

Tags: file-management, document-indexing

I will be using an an external SSD drive to store PDF and Word documents, but I'll add media (pictures, videos), Spreadsheets and Power Point files too.

I am looking for any solution to organize and index the files. An idea that I had would be to make it possible to set tags or descriptions to the files, so the search and indexation may be done faster.

It is a 1TB storage, so I expect to have many many many files. I could create the structure by myself or to use locate32 to create an Index, but I am looking for a more professional tool or solution.

Thank you in advance.

Kind regards.

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at something like [Recoll](https://www.lesbonscomptes.com/recoll/).

It enables [indexing of external drives](https://www.lesbonscomptes.com/recoll/usermanual/webhelp/docs/RCL.INDEXING.REMOVABLE.html), caters for many file types, etc. it also runs on Windows, Linux, Mac OSX.

This [datahoarder forum](https://old.reddit.com/r/DataHoarder/search?q=organize%20and%20index%20files%20external%20drive&restrict_sr=on) may also have some good suggestions.